# flutter setstate rebuild only one child

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

in flutter I need that when I call setstate, it only rebuilds a widget

I put 2 children in a stack, I need that when a button is pressed, only the second one is rebuilt.

```
bool popup = false;

Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('TEST'),
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(                       // + BUTTON
        icon: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            popup = true;
          });
        },
      ),
      IconButton(                       // - BUTTON
        icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            popup = false;
          });
      ),
    ],
  ),
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[

        Container(                                        // FIRST WIDGET
          key: ValueKey(1),
          child: Text("Random - "+new Random().nextInt(20).toString())
        ),

        popup ? Center(child: Text("abc")) : Text("") ,   // SECOND WIDGET

      ],

    ),
  ),
);
```

I expect that when I press the "+" button only the second widget will be re-built, but now it will rebuild all the contents of the stack.

thank you all.

Comment: `rebuild` means rebuilding the whole page based on the current state. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Can't I just rebuild a widget by calling the setstate of the parent widget?

Comment: I expect that when I press the "+" button only the second widget will be re-built

Comment: Should probably not think about minimizing rebuilding that much. I did it aswell at the start and it just eats time. Flutter is fast enough

Answer (score 5):

From the [official docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/best-practices) we can read:

*"When setState() is called on a State, all descendent widgets rebuild. Therefore, localize the setState() call to the part of the subtree whose UI actually needs to change. Avoid calling setState() high up in the tree if the change is contained to a small part of the tree."*

My suggestion, and I use it most of the times, is separate the widget that you want to rebuild in a new StatefulWidget. This way the setState only will be rebuild that widget.

```
    class MyAppBar extends StatefulWidget
    ...
    class _MyAppBarState extends State<MyAppBar> {
    bool popup = false;

     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return AppBar(
           title: const Text('TEST'),
           actions: <Widget>[
           IconButton(                       // + BUTTON
             icon: Icon(Icons.add),
             onPressed: () {
               setState(() {
               popup = true;
             });
            },
           ),
          IconButton(                       // - BUTTON
            icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
              popup = false;
            });
          ),
        ],
       ), 
      }
```

Then call it in your Scaffold:

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: MyAppBar(),
```

Other method I can suggest is using **ValueNotifier** or **notifyListeners()**. Please read this page [Avoid rebuilding all the widgets repetitively](https://blog.codemagic.io/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-your-flutter-app./). It is well explained.

Comment: separating the widget to new StatefulWidget did actually helped.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use ValueListenableBuilder:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final ValueNotifier<bool> popup = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('TEST'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              // + BUTTON
              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () {
                popup.value = true;
              }),
          IconButton(
              // - BUTTON
              icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
              onPressed: () {
                popup.value = false;
              })
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
            valueListenable: popup,
            builder: (context, value, _) {
              return Stack(
                children: [
                  Text("Random - " + new Random().nextInt(20).toString()),
                  popup.value ? Center(child: Text("abc")) : Text(""),
                ],
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This actually does update only part of the child tree

Answer (score 1):

You can use StreamBuilder:

```dart
  StreamController<bool> popup = StreamController<bool>();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    popup.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('TEST'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(                       // + BUTTON
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () => popup.add(true),
          ),
          IconButton(                       // - BUTTON
            icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
            onPressed: () => popup.add(false),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(                                        // FIRST WIDGET
              key: ValueKey(1),
              child: Text("Random - "+new Random().nextInt(20).toString())
            ),
            StreamBuilder<bool>(
              stream: popup.stream,
              initialData: false,
              builder: (cxt, snapshot) {
                return snapshot.data ? Center(child: Text("abc")) : Text("");
              },
            )
          ],

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the setState from the widget you don't want to be changed. And only use setState for the ones you need to rebuild

Or you can consider using inheritedModel widget

Comment: setstate is on the parent widget

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example from where you can learn how to build an Inherited model widget to update only specific widgets rather than the whole widgets.

https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-state-management-setstate-fn-is-the-easiest-and-the-most-powerful-44703c97f035