# How can I refresh an individual List Tile in a Listview.builder? Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, listview

Situation:

1. I have an 'Event' item that you can click on --> Event detail screen.
2. That has individual subitems (date,participants,description) in the form of a list.
3. I load the subitems with a `Future Builder` into a `Listview.builder` with a List Tile like so:
   [image]
4. I have a button to edit the location, it saves to the database and locally updates the location variable. This calls **`SetState()`**.
5. The full list is updated, even if some tiles don't have changes.

**THE PROBLEM**
Some tiles, like the *participants tile* needs to load pictures and some other things that are time intensive. So even if I just change the location and update the list, everything reloads, consuming resources and taking too much time to load a simple string.

### WHAT I AM LOOKING FOR

Is it possible to reload only a certain list tile? Would you use another widget instead of ListView.builder? Other logic? Any help is appreciated.

### Answer Extension [Update]

The marked answer is correct. I was using future builder and that was forcing me to reload all data always. By using different Streams with Streambuilder I am able to change data on database and it automatically changes on the UI, without updating the state! Magic.

Comment: You should put the UI that needs re-building in a separate Stateful widget. Perhaps this question/answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58692462/flutter-setstate-rebuild-only-one-child

Comment: Yes, however I would need to put a stateful widget around the list tile in the builder. Then all list tiles would have the same one.  Wouldn't that be the same?

Comment: Or I need to find a way for only the data that is changed to be updated, even automatically. That is why I am exploring Stream Builder...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

base on what i notices, `Future Builder` is the problem, Future builder rebuild the whole widget in the ListView.builder. in your case use `StreamBuilder` and you see the changes you what...

Comment: I am exploring the idea of a Stream Builder for the data. But how can I combine it with a Firebase RTDB query? That is, the stream should update the value on screen when it is changed in the database, using the onValue() function for the query.