# the setstate changes all of the items in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem that my code is working fine when I tap on one product button, but when I tap on the other one it mixes up, So basically when I tap on the one product it changes the button as I want but when I tap another one it changes the state of first one, this all mix up is happening. I know that the error is causing because of isCarted variable is set to false or true but I don't know how to solve it here is my code:

```
   import 'dart:ffi';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:groccer_app/Drawer/categories/prodetails.dart';
import 'package:add_to_cart_animation/add_to_cart_animation.dart';

class Products extends StatefulWidget {
  final String imgUrl;
  final String title;
  final String quantity;
  final String prodetail;
  final String price;
  final Function ontap;
  final String docId;
  // final bool carted;
  const Products(
      {super.key,
      required this.imgUrl,
      required this.title,
      required this.quantity,
      required this.price,
      required this.prodetail,
      required this.ontap,
      // required this.carted,
      required this.docId});

  @override
  State<Products> createState() => _ProductsState();
}

class _ProductsState extends State<Products> {
  bool isCarted = false;
  getdata() async {
    if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Admin')
          .doc('products')
          .collection('IsCarted')
          .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
          .collection("UserData")
          .get()
          .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
          if (doc["CartedDoc"] == widget.docId) {
            setState(() {
              isCarted = true;
            });
          } else {
            setState(() {
              isCarted = false;
            });
          }
          // print(doc["CartedDoc"] == widget.docId);
        });
      });
      // print(isCarted.toString() + "carted");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getdata();
    return Container(
      // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: widget.imgUrl != "" &&
              widget.price != "" &&
              widget.title != "" &&
              widget.prodetail != "" &&
              widget.quantity != ""
          ? Column(children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  // print("dd");
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => productDetails(
                                detail: widget.prodetail,
                                imageUrl: widget.imgUrl,
                                price: widget.price,
                                title: widget.title,
                                quantity: widget.quantity,
                              )));
                  setState(() {
                    // categoriesList[index]['isExpanded'] = !isExpanded;
                    // categoriesList[index]['icon'] = isExpanded
                    //     ? Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_rounded
                    //     : Icons.keyboard_arrow_up_rounded;
                  });
                },
                child: Card(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          // key: widgetKey,
                          width: 60,
                          height: 60,
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          child: Image.network(
                            widget.imgUrl,
                            // width: 100,
                            // height: 100,
                          ),
                        ), // widget to be displayed inside the avatar
                        // Image.asset(
                        //   category['imagePath'],
                        //   width: 150,
                        // ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 16.0),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                child: Text(widget.title,
                                    // "Onion - Pyaz",
                                    // style: const TextStyle(
                                    //   fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    // ),
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                        fontSize: 15)),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 7.0),
                              Text(
                                widget.quantity,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(146, 146, 146, 1.0)),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 50.0),
                              Text("Rs: " + widget.price,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                                      fontSize: 17,
                                      color: Color.fromRGBO(230, 0, 57, 1.0))),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: [
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 40,
                            ),
                            const Icon(
                              Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded,
                              // category['icon'],
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(193, 193, 193, 1.0),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 30,
                            ),
                            isCarted == false
                                ? ElevatedButton(
                                    //           onPressed: () async {
                                    //             CollectionReference collref =
                                    //     await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                    //         .collection('Admin')
                                    //         .doc('products')
                                    //         .collection('IsCarted')
                                    //         .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
                                    //         .collection("UserData");
                                    // await collref.add({
                                    //   "CartedDoc": widget.docId,
                                    // });
                                    //             // widget.ontap();
                                    //             print("this" + isCarted.toString());
                                    //           },
                                    onPressed: () async {
                                      CollectionReference collref =
                                          await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                              .collection('Admin')
                                              .doc('products')
                                              .collection('IsCarted')
                                              .doc(FirebaseAuth
                                                  .instance.currentUser!.uid)
                                              .collection("UserData");

                                      // Add the document to the collection and wait for the operation to complete
                                      await collref
                                          .add({"CartedDoc": widget.docId});

                                      // Update the state and print the value of `isCarted`
                                      setState(() {
                                        isCarted = true;
                                        print("this " + isCarted.toString());
                                      });
                                    },

                                    child: const Text(
                                      "Add to Cart",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                              191, 232, 203, 1.0)),
                                    ),
                                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                        backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(
                                            25, 174, 68, 1.0),
                                        elevation: 0),
                                  )
                                : ElevatedButton(
                                    onPressed: () async {
                                      //                   CollectionReference collref =
                                      //     await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                      //         .collection('Admin')
                                      //         .doc('products')
                                      //         .collection('IsCarted')
                                      //         .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
                                      //         .collection("UserData");
                                      // await collref.add({
                                      //   "CartedDoc": doc.id,
                                      // });
                                      if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser !=
                                          null) {
                                        CollectionReference collref =
                                            await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                                .collection('Admin')
                                                .doc('products')
                                                .collection('IsCarted')
                                                .doc(FirebaseAuth
                                                    .instance.currentUser!.uid)
                                                .collection("UserData");
                                        collref.get().then(
                                            (QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
                                          querySnapshot.docs
                                              .forEach((doc) async {
                                            // if (doc["CartedDoc"] == widget.docId) {
                                            //   setState(() {
                                            //     isCarted = true;
                                            //   });
                                            // } else {
                                            //   isCarted = false;
                                            // }
                                            await doc.reference.delete();
                                            // print(doc["CartedDoc"] == widget.docId);
                                          });
                                        });
                                      }
                                      setState(() {
                                        isCarted = false;
                                        print("this " + isCarted.toString());
                                      });
                                      // getdata();
                                    },
                                    style: ButtonStyle(
                                        backgroundColor:
                                            MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
                                                (states) => Colors.white),
                                        elevation:
                                            MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                                                (states) => 0),
                                        side: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<
                                            BorderSide>(
                                          (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                                            // if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
                                            //   // return null;
                                            // }
                                            return BorderSide(
                                                color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                                    25, 174, 68, 1.0),
                                                width:
                                                    3); // set border color here
                                          },
                                        )),
                                    // onPressed: () async {
                                    //   widget.ontap();
                                    //   print("this" + isCarted.toString());
                                    // },
                                    // child: const Text(
                                    //   "Added to Cart",
                                    //   style: TextStyle(
                                    //       color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                    //           191, 232, 203, 1.0)),
                                    // ),
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Icon(
                                          Icons.delete,
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),

                                    //   style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                    //       backgroundColor: Colors.white,

                                    // )
                                  )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ])
          : Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Whenever a build method doesn't fit on one screen, I'd suggest creating some new widget classes that extend StatelessWidget or StatefulWidget so that you can easily see what your code is doing.  This will make it much easier to ask questions that are more focused on a smaller block of code.  My guess is that you might need to be using a Key somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should you always call GetData() inside the build method?

Don’t call setState in build methods.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       getdata();
       return Container(....
```

use FutureBuilder.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return FutureBuilder(
              future: getdata(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                 return Container(....
```

Have a nice coding life. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this question and the the answers to it. I believe it will help out:

[flutter setstate rebuild only one child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58692462/flutter-setstate-rebuild-only-one-child/72418944#72418944)